# Memory doesn't free up after closing forms

Tags: c#, telerik

I've tried analyzing our program memory dump. I opened and closed the form multiple times. The first pic shows before I open and close form then 2nd is after I open and close form.

[image]

[image]

Is this normal? Sometimes the users encounters memory exception error. I used `form.dispose` to close the form. What should I do?

Comment: How do you close your forms?

Comment: Why are you using Dispose() instead of Close()?

Comment: @tofik I've tried adding this.dispose on form closing event to no avail

Comment: @D.Go Disposing the form frees up the unmanaged resources that the form is holding onto.

Comment: _Disposing the form frees up the unmanaged resources that the form is holding onto._ You ceate it you dispose of it. Do not rely on Form to do it for you. Also: Garbage collection is only started when the system deems it useful and/or necessary

Comment: Did you investigate your app for memory leaks? Are there zombie objects? Does the LOH become more fragmented?

Comment: @dymanoid zombie objects and LOH are jargons word to me. I'll study it and let you know.? Thanks

Comment: using (Form2 form = new form2())
            {
                form.showdialog();
            }

By using this I'm closing the form and all the objects inside the form?